# Why are mediawiki magic words CURRENTMONTH and CURRENTDAY2 giving a date in the future?

Tags: timezone, mediawiki

On my wiki homepage I have a shortcut to create a "blog post" with the current date as the title:

```html
<inputbox>
type=create
default=Blog: {{CURRENTYEAR}}-{{CURRENTMONTH}}-{{CURRENTDAY2}}
buttonlabel=Create post
</inputbox>
```

However near midnight, the date appears in the future, like so, when the local date is 2023-08-31:

[image: Text field with date 2023-09-01]

I have in my `/etc/mediawiki/LocalSettings.php` the timezone that matches my local timezone:

```php
$wgLocaltimezone = "America/Chicago";
```

So issue is not that the server's local time is UTC.

Answer (score 3):

From the MediaWiki documentation: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#Date_and_time

> #### Date and time
>
> The following variables return the current date and time in UTC.
>
> ...
>
> {{CURRENTYEAR}}
>
> {{CURRENTMONTH}}
>
> etc

However below that it also provides local timezone variables:

> The following variables do the same as the preceding ones but using the site's server config or $wgLocaltimezone.
>
> {{LOCALYEAR}}
>
> {{LOCALMONTH}}
>
> etc

So in this case the solution is to use `{{LOCAL*}}` variables, like so:

```html
<inputbox>
type=create
default=Blog: {{LOCALYEAR}}-{{LOCALMONTH}}-{{LOCALDAY2}}
buttonlabel=Create post
</inputbox>
```